# Compute Utilization using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:-

[image]

I need to compute the truck utilization rate & the final output should be as follows:-

i.  Utilization (Daily):-

[image]

ii. Average Utilisation from 1st May to 3 May: 44.4% 
[(33.3% + 33.3% + 66.7%) / 3]

iii.    Average Utilisation from 1st May to 6 May: 55.6%
[(33.3% + 33.3% + 66.7% + 66.7% + 66.7% + 66.7%) / 6]

How can I generate the above output?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Is this homework?

Comment: Can anyone else see the pictures? They're showing as broken links for me.

Comment: Will there be any missing dates. If yes, should that be considered for `Average Utilization` between two dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `SUM` and `COUNT` like this

```
DECLARE @SampleDAta AS TABLE
(
    Truck varchar(10),
    Status varchar(10),
    Date date 
)
INSERT INTO @SampleDAta
(
    Truck,
    Status,
    [Date]
)
VALUES
('A', 'OFF', '2017-05-01'),
('A', 'OFF', '2017-05-02'),
('A', 'OFF', '2017-05-03'),
('A', 'OFF', '2017-05-04'),
('A', 'OFF', '2017-05-05'),
('A', 'OFF', '2017-05-06'),
('B', 'ON', '2017-05-01'),
('B', 'ON', '2017-05-02'),
('B', 'ON', '2017-05-03'),
('B', 'ON', '2017-05-04'),
('B', 'ON', '2017-05-05'),
('B', 'ON', '2017-05-06'),
('C', 'OFF', '2017-05-01'),
('C', 'OFF', '2017-05-02'),
('C', 'ON', '2017-05-03'),
('C', 'ON', '2017-05-04'),
('C', 'ON', '2017-05-05'),
('C', 'ON', '2017-05-06')

-- I.
SELECT sd.[Date], 
      CAST(100.00 * SUM(CASE WHEN sd.Status = 'ON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/ COUNT(sd.Truck)  AS decimal(10,2)) AS [Utilisation Rate]  
FROM @SampleDAta sd
GROUP BY sd.[Date]

-- II.
;WITH temp AS 
(
    SELECT sd.[Date], 
      CAST(100.00 * SUM(CASE WHEN sd.Status = 'ON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/ COUNT(sd.Truck)  AS decimal(10,2)) AS [Utilisation Rate]  
    FROM @SampleDAta sd
    GROUP BY sd.[Date]

)
SELECT  
      CAST(SUM(t.[Utilisation Rate])/ COUNT(*) AS decimal(10,2)) AS [Utilisation Rate]  
FROM temp t
WHERE t.[Date] BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-03'

-- III.
;WITH temp AS 
(
    SELECT sd.[Date], 
      CAST(100.00 * SUM(CASE WHEN sd.Status = 'ON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/ COUNT(sd.Truck)  AS decimal(10,2)) AS [Utilisation Rate]  
    FROM @SampleDAta sd
    GROUP BY sd.[Date]

)
SELECT  
      CAST(SUM(t.[Utilisation Rate])/ COUNT(*) AS decimal(10,2)) AS [Utilisation Rate]  
FROM temp t
WHERE t.[Date] BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-06'
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/EQIU21411

Comment: Second and third query can be simplified like this http://rextester.com/KICEK85223